# Scheme: Mysterious void in pattern match

Tags: scheme, pattern-matching, racket, void

I am writing a function called annotate that uses match-lambda -- often with recursive calls to annotate.  Here is one of the pattern matches:

```
(`(lambda (,<param1> . ,<params>) ,<stmts>)
 `(CLOSURE ENV (,<param1> . ,<params>) (lambda (ENV) ,(map annotate (map (lambda (x) (append `(,<param1> . ,<params>) (list x))) `(,<stmts>))))))
```

However, when this pattern is matched this is what returns:

```
'(CLOSURE
  ENV
  (x)
  (lambda (ENV)
    ((CLOSURE
      ENV
      (x y)
      (lambda (ENV) ((+ x y))))))
  #<void>)
```

Specifically I can't figure out where "void" is coming from.  In fact, if I include the line:

```
,(displayln (map annotate (map (lambda (x) (append `(,<param1> . ,<params>) (list x))) `(,<stmts>))))
```

it prints:

```
((CLOSURE ENV (x y) (lambda (ENV) ((+ x y)))))
```

notably without "void".

If someone could tell me what the problem is it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `#<void>` is the return value from `displayln`.  Output functions in some implementations of Scheme and Racket usually return that when there is nothing meaningful to return.

Comment: *Scheme* has unspecified results for output functions; it's *Racket* that returns this `#<void>` value in this case.

Comment: @Eli: Yes, I guess; standard Scheme doesn't even have `#<void>`, does it?  I'll fix my answer.

Comment: Yes, the standard just doesn't specify anything; some implementations choose a specific value for this unspecified result, and some choose to return some other value.

Comment: I'm confused.  When I include the displayln function it prints the results of map annotate without #void.  Without the displayln function #void appears in the pattern match.

Comment: @Schemer: How are you including the `displayln` function when it works?  The Racket REPL will not print out `#<void>` values.

Comment: Jeremiah: S/He's using it inside a list, where it is visible.  Try `(list (displayln "blah"))`.

Comment: @Eli: I don't know that the "when I include the displayln function" comment refers to a case where `displayln` is in a list.  I would imagine it should include a void there too, unless some later pattern match is removing it.